# Test if the player's desired movement exceeds a magnitude?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Say I have a point in a Vector3, and my FPSController (I'm using the standard one that comes with Unity 5) moves a magnitude of 10 away from this Vector3.  I want to not allow movement, in any direction, beyond magnitude 10.  Ideally, I would anticipate which direction the player pressed to move in, test that vector, and if it's below magnitude of 10 then it'll allow the movement to proceed.  That way, if you're at 10 and press "back", you wont be able to move but if you press "forward" then no problem.

I know I'm being a bit abstract here.  From what I understand the FPSController.cs script is using the CharacterController component.  I've studied the FPSController code for awhile tonight and notice it's doing all sorts of calculations on the local position, but the magnitude needs to be between two world coordinates.

I know how to calculate the magnitude already, all I need to know is how to test the anticipated direction.  I have a feeling it's easier than I think?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "I want to not allow movement, in any direction, beyond magnitude 10." Are you saying that you want to constrain the player to within 10 units from a certain point? Or do you want to restrain their velocity?

Comment: I want to restrain them 10 units from a certain point.  You're attached to a rope and once it's stretched to its length you can't go any further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking this! Instead of thinking how you can constrain velocity, think about constraining position. Check out [`Vector3 Vector3.ClampMagnitude(Vector3, float)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html), which returns the vector scaled to a maximum length. By "transforming" the player position to the target, clamping to the max length, then transforming back to world coordinates you can constrain the player's position.

```
// target: the Vector3 you can't get too far from.
// distance: the float max distance from the target.
transform.position = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(transform.position - target, distance) + target;
```

Comment: Great idea! But how do I prevent the character controller from moving?  In a very simple top down game if the user presses right it will check first if there's a wall there and if not then it will allow the movement to happen.   So the final piece of this puzzle is how do I tell the fps controller not to proceed beyond the max length? I've tried injecting an if clause within the fpscontroller.cs script in the update areas but that brought the fps to a crawl obviously because it was doing the distance calculation every frame.   I want to only do this check if new input is detected

Comment: @mythstified It's surprising that this would slow your game at all--it's a tiny amount of computation. All you should need is to run this every update at the very end to clamp the player within the bounding sphere. You should edit your question to add the code as "what I've tried". Edit: by the way, as a general tip, when you want to make your game not lag you want to consider the *most* that can happen on a given frame, so optimizing by not doing something while the player's not moving isn't a great optimization, because the player's usually moving.

Comment: That..actually..worked... I'll give you the green check!  I still feel weird tho, it's as if it's first allowing the movement then moving the character back.. but.. it works

Comment: @mythstified This is (the root of) how some physics engines work, so at least realize you're in good company! And I suggest keeping firm in your mind that anything that happens "between" frames doesn't matter as long as the state while rendered matches what you want.

Comment: That's good advice! I guess that clamp operation is just multiplying vectors and positioning a transform are pretty darn cheap operations that I shouldn't need to worry about one quick repositioning between the frames